# Spring Security in Grails redirects to IP after login

Tags: grails, spring-security, tomcat7

I am running a Grails 2.4.2 app in a Tomcat 7 for ubuntu.

I  have the problem that after login, page is redirected to IP.

> Before login
>   www.app.com/login
>   After login
>   104.21.22.23/login

I tried to configure grails.serverURL but that did not make any difference. My current value for grails.serverURL is "www.app.com"

Comment: try commenting `grails.serverURL` from config file

Answer (score 0):

in answer, I am considering you are using grails 2.4.2

In your `BuildConfig.groovy` file add following:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/YOUR_APP__URL'
```

above will work with latest version of grails also.

You can check all options [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/2.0.x/guide/urlProperties.html)

Comment: I am facing same issue

Comment: `'/YOUR_APP__URL'` here type your home controller e.g. `'/home'`

Comment: I know ,  '/YOUR_APP__URL' should be changed. I have changed that value to my Controller

Comment: Spring Security version?

Comment: I am using spring-security-core:1.2.7.3 library.